# Invalid data type for parameter passed in the cursor in SAP HANA

Tags: variables, types, cursor

Can anybody help me,as I want to declare a cursor with a variable which is of table type and I am getting invalid data type for parameter. In a stored procedure in SAP HANA

Create TYPE "TT_GUID" AS TABLE ( "guid" VARCHAR(32));

DECLARE CURSOR C_cursor( var_guid "TT_GUID") FOR

Select zval_001,zval_002
FROM  "table1"
Where "guid" = :var_guid ;